# Json value count=0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

The JSON data structure is as follows:

```json
{
    "Train":
    {
        "Name":"Ekspres",
        "Wagons":
        [
            {"Name":"Wagon 1", "Capacity":100, "FullSeatNumber":68},
            {"Name":"Wagon 2", "Capacity":90, "FullSeatNumber":50},
            {"Name":"Wagon 3", "Capacity":80, "FullSeatNumber":80}
        ]
    },
    "PersonReservation":3,
    "DifferentWagon":true
}
```

Class structures are as follows:

```
 public class Root
    {
        public Train Train { get; set; }
        public int PersonReservation { get; set; }
        public bool DifferentWagon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Train
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Wagon> Wagons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wagon
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public int FullSeatNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

The JSON data sent in Swagger is shown above. After submitting this data the wagon data is not available as below:

[image]

The wagon value is 0 when the JSON data operations shown in the picture are sent.

Wagons
JSON [HTMLPOST] send to WAGONS count=0
WHY?

Comment: You sending the parameters in Query strings, which is not what you need probably. Add [FromBody] before Root
like 'Post([FromBody] Root root)`

Comment: Tested according to the controller method provided in your picture and there is no problem you describe. Are you using `[FromQuery]`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NikitaChayka controller worked after editing, Thank you 
[HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Root root)
  {
   string value = "test";
   return Ok(root);
  }